# Improving speed of report preview in MS SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have about a big database in SQL and while I'm creating a report in SSRS, I'd like to display just say first 100 rows, so I don't need to wait a coffee time until in loads all database records for my preview.
How can I do that?

Here's my project: http://www.filedropper.com/wasalesrevenuereport

Comment: select top 100?

Comment: Just don't forget to take it out when you deploy!! Of, course if you post your query, we might be able to spot something

Comment: I'm very new to the SSRS and there's no query box like in SSMS to write the SQL syntax.
I've uploaded my project file to http://www.filedropper.com/wasalesrevenuereport. For now, I divided that into pages, so the data are loaded just for particular country. But, be able to toggle all database by countries and see summaries are for some columns is otherwise hugely time-consuming